# Get PID on remote computer via service name

Tags: powershell

I need to kill a process behind a service on a remote computer with PowerShell for a program/script I am creating.

The problem is that the process doesn't always have the same PID and the name is not always the same either. The only thing that always is the same is the name.

I have found out that I can get the PID of the service with this command:

```
taskkill /s rasmuspc /u rasmus123 /p 12345 /PID (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service|where{$_.Name -eq 'Spooler'}).ProcessID /F
```

I use this command to skip `tasklist`, so I can make it automated instead of manually looking up and typing in the PID.

But that command will only get the PID from my own computer, and I can't see is there a way to to get the PID of a service on a remote PC, only knowing the name of the service?

Comment: Have you tried with `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName remotepcname`?

Comment: Why don't you just remote the whole command with `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen is correct. In your Get-WMI command you don't tell WMI what computer you want to get the PID from so it defaults to getting the PID for the service your running the command on, not the server you want to connect to.

Comment: Thank you Mathias and Jeroen, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Taskkill /s rasmuspc /u rasmus123 /p 12345 /PID (Get-WmiObject -CN $remotepcname -filter 'name="spooler"}).processID /F
```

Thanks to Mathias R. Jessen, this command worked.

Comment: Filter left, format right. `Get-WmiObject -CN $remotepcname -filter 'name="spooler"'`

Answer (score 1):

tasklist /s *Server name*. 
This can be used to get the list of tasks running on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

try this

`Get-Process -ComputerName "ServerName" -Name notepad | stop-Process`

you need to have able in the remote machine to stop process

Answer (score 0):

To kill a corresponding process in Powershell, one line:

```
Get-Process -PID (Get-WmiObject -CN $RemotePCName -filter 'name="spooler"' -Class Win32_service).processID | Stop-Process -Force
```